# Is paypal legal for getting payment for android app in Turkey where google payment system is not supported?

Tags: android, google-play, payment

I developed an android app, and i want to sell this app in google play,however I'm in Turkey and selling system is not supported by google in Turkey.

I want to learn the answer of this question. Does google allow when i placed a buy button which opens browsers and redirect to paypal payment web page  in my app ? Does google allow this ? or Does google remove my application from google play for illegal selling method issue.If so what can i do for selling my app in google play.

Thanks for your valuable answers.

- Edit 1

I find some app which uses  PayPal services in their app and placed in google play's free apps category such as [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=biz.apporiginal.creditcall) if it is not allowed then why are these apps still surfacing on the play store ?

- Edit 2

I want to discuss my technique in my app.

1. User download the app from google play
2. App is about fast reading and has 12 levels
3. User can use level 1 for free as demo others are locked
4. If user want to use other level, there is a
   button which opens my website page
5. I post the deviceId of the phone or tablet, record it to my db and redirect browser to   paypal payment page, if payment successfull, paypal page redirects browser to my page to set payment done,so that i can understand which device has done payment
6. Then my server has an application which checks
   the successfull payments and send push message to the user
   device,that msg changes the application to full version , user can
   start to use other levels without downloading the full version ,

And my thoughts, user can use the app from google play store just for one level,this is legal because user can use it free, I use my own servers for payment mechanism,after payment my app in user's device is turn to full version without any google play's affords.So this is legal.
Think all is legal.

Comment: Nope, you will still have to relase the app as "free" by Google's Terms of Use. Managing your own app-purchase system might not be in the spirit of the Android ecosystem.... that being said, earn what you must. I'm Serbian, and TMK I can't release apps for anything other than "Free app".

Comment: I beleive the free demo version would be on Google Play, but the alternatively-paid-for would have to reside on your server somewhere, and you'd have to take up all validation and refunds by yourself. I don't know, it's easier to just upload as someone else that can charge money for it... but then, the app isn't yours, it's that someone elses. Tho if you get to keep the money, who cares right?

Comment: You are misinterpreting "not supported" as "not allowed". The "not allowed" part comes in later, and is tied to certain specifics (like not selling profile information), but for your intents and purposes - if Google doesn't provide payment out-of-box, you will have a hard time making it work with Paypal, because **you** have to take care of everything your self. That 'credit call' app seems to have it's own "credit server" which you refill using paypal. The app itself isn't paid for by paypal, only a subset of it's functionality is - essentially making it an in-app purchase.

Comment: To be more clear "you cannot charge downloading of your app via paypal for downloads made via Google PLAY store" however "once inside the app, you can offer someone to go to your website and process him as a customer there, delivering the APK via your original freebie one after he authenticated as a valid customer". See about [APK Expansion files](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_4_-_apk_expansion_files)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Paypal In-App model for Android legal on Android Market?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042603/is-paypal-in-app-model-for-android-legal-on-android-market)

Comment: questions about Terms of Service are offtopic

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is legal. Uploading app to google and charging for it there is much easier since google does everything else for you. You just set the price and cash flows to your bank account.

But ofcourse you can also do it your way, but it would be much more complicated for you. People who'd buy your app wouldn't have their app automatically updated like if they downloaded it from google play, you'd have to manage all the refunds while google does it automatically for you, you'd probably have to send people the apk after they bought it which means your app would be easier to crack.

It has it's flaws but I'm almost 100% sure it's legal.

EDIT: Read the comments below, it isn't as legal as I thought it was :p

Comment: I suggest you reevaluate your certainty.

Comment: Well, it is legal according to google play, isn't it? Owning an android phone doesn't mean you HAVE to download/buy every single app from google play. I don't know if your country's laws would say the same, though.

Comment: Google imposes release criteria on you the developer, not downloading criteria on the end-user.

And I'm guessing the whole point of this is to avoid having to root your phone to use this app.

According to Google, there are only three legitimate ways of deploying an APK to a device - 1) google play, 2) adb install <apk> 3) adb push to /system/app, and I don't know how "random apk website" factors in this when it comes to non-power users. If your user can't find the "allow unknown sources to install applications" option - you're screwed.

Comment: Mind you - i'm not arguing the illegality of setting up your own AppStore. Sounds legal but has big overhead for a small app. But there's a difference between it sound legal to you and me, and a professional in the field of law and it won't take much for some asshole lawyear tearing you a new one on court. Then again, they can probably sue overseas till the cows come back home, Turks won't care. I'm in the same boat, so I'm interested in this topic :)

Comment: You've got a huge point, thanks for changing my point of view :) I'm also in the same boat, Slovenia, can't sell any of my apps and I'm not even interested in selling them on my own, sounds like too much work, I'll just wait until my country is supported :)

Comment: Or, get a trusted American(tm) buddy to setup a developer account and use him as your "developer face" :)

Comment: That's another option, I've been thinking of doing that for a while now with my german buddy. Does anyone know if there's a way to use him as my "developer face" but still get funds directly to my bank account? I don't want to put too much work on him since he would probably get the money first and then redirects it to my account.

Comment: If you use a developer face, you need to account for one additional hoop in the cash-funneling process. After all, it's not much different from any sort of Proxy :D

Comment: @Shark Do you know if there's any kind of tutorial/explanation on how to set up a developer face in a different country?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it follows the same rules as when opening a bank account under a fake name :) j/k. I'm thinking it would have to be an honest agreement between two parties in which one really doesn't benefit from the deal at all and is doing it just for sake of helping, and the other party not having an option or grounds to check whether or not full "booked" profit has landed on his account. In other words, you'd have to be friends first, and the sorta friends that don't break a friendship over some app "pocket change".

Comment: It seems like what he's asking is "can I put the app for free in the app store, then have people click a link within the app that directs them to a paypal website where they pay to unlock a feature". Answer is yes. However, that could be a lot of work to setup all on your own.

Answer (score 0):

In the event that it isn't, you're just using the application, so having an extra-national bank account that it flows into and transferring those funds into your Turkey-based account would be legal. That being said, you'd be paying tax twice, which isn't too great for profits, but you do what you have to eh, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have read that only 18 countries can accept PayPal Payment other than Google Wallet. But we still want to make payment via PayPal.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2651410?hl=en